# $\frac{\cos\theta }{1-\sin\theta }\cdot \frac{1+\sin\theta }{1+\sin\theta }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm having trouble can someone help and explain step by step on how I can simplify the answer?

Comment: $1-\cos^2\theta=?$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

You have $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ and $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, therefore
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\cos t}{1-\sin t}\cdot \frac{1+\sin t}{1+\sin t}
 &= \frac{\cos t(1+\sin t)}{(1-\sin t)(1+\sin t)} \\
 &= \frac{\cos t(1+\sin t)}{1^2-\sin^2 t} \\
 &= \frac{\cos t(1+\sin t)}{\cos^2 t} \\
\end{split}
$$

Can you finish?